# Hermitian operators $\langle Av,v\rangle=0$ for all $v\in V$ then $A=0$ proof

Tags: linear-algebra

> Theorem: Let $V$ be as before. If $A$ is an operator such that $\langle Av,v\rangle=0$ for all $v\in V$ then $A=0$.

Proof: The left hand side of the polarization identity is equal to $0$ for all $v,w\in V$. Hence we obtain

$\langle Aw,v\rangle+\langle Av,w\rangle=0$

for all $v,w\in V$.Replace $v$ by $iv$. Then by the rules for the hermitian product, we obtain

$-i\langle Aw,v\rangle+i\langle Av,w\rangle=0$

whence

$-\langle Aw,v\rangle+\langle Av,w\rangle=0$

Adding this to the first relation obtained above yields

$2\langle Av,w\rangle=0$

whence $\langle Av,w\rangle=0$. Hence $A=0$,as was to be shown.$\blacksquare $ ***Linear Algebra, by Serge Lang.***

> Polarization identity:
>
> $\langle A(v+w),v+w\rangle-\langle A(v-w),v-w\rangle=2[\langle Av,w\rangle+\langle Aw,v\rangle]$
>
> for all $v,w\in V$, or also
>
> $\langle A(v+w),v+w\rangle- \langle A(v),v\rangle-\langle A(w),w\rangle=\langle Av,w\rangle+\langle Aw,v\rangle$

I am not understanding this proof.

**Questions:**

**1)** $\langle Av,v\rangle=0$ Why is not implicit that $A=0$? Why is not straightforward that $\langle Av,w\rangle=0$?

**2)** "Adding this to the first relation obtained above yields $2\langle Av,w\rangle=0$" How does the author delivers this conclusion? What relation is the author referring to?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) In matrix terms, and working
over the reals, we have the hypothesis $v^t A v=0$ for all vectors
$v$. This does **not** imply $v^t Aw=0$ for all $v$ and $w$. Consider
$\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}$. To get this implication we need symmetry. Here the
analogue of symmetry is the Hermitian condition.

(2)
$$2\left<Av,w\right>
=(\left<Aw,v\right>+\left<Av,w\right>)
+(-\left<Aw,v\right>+\left<Av,w\right>).$$

Comment: This is just a subjective question. I have an interest on how people think about these issues and how deep one´s thoughts can go. Since I am selfstudying, I cannot evaluate or compare my understanding with others. You talk about the matrix example which gave a way of understanding the question. Whenever you think of this theorem do you see that example? Or can you think in a more abstract way? Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: @PedroGomes I have seen these ideas used in many contexts. Also I find it useful to consider how a general idea works in simple examples. Here a one-dimensional $V$ would be too simple, but a two-dimensional $V$ does throw up some insights.